# assigning variables in Ruby blocks to higher scope

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the retriable gem.

I have a function that returns a value that's wrapped inside a retriable block like below.

```
Retriable.retriable do
    x = some_function(1, 2)
end

....do something with x...
```

The only way I've figured out how to do this is by using a global variable i.e @x inside the block but I don't think that's necessarily the best way.  I would appreciate it if someone could point me to a better way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: `@x` is called "instance variable", btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact case can be solved like this:

```
x = Retriable.retriable do
  some_function(1, 2)
end
```

But in general, no, you can't declare variables in outer scopes. That's why we ***have*** scopes.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, you solve this by declaring the variable outside the loop:

```
x = nil

%w[foo bar baz].each do |word|
  x = word
end

puts x # => "baz"
```

See it in action here: https://repl.it/@jrunning/AbsoluteShamelessVerification

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign a value to a new variable by whatever the block returns so:

```
x = Retriable.retriable do
  some_function(1, 2)
end
```

Comment: What's the point of providing an answer that is identical to an earlier answer?